# UIImage.pngData() - a struct or a closure?

Tags: swift, uiimage

I am massively confused about what UIImage.pngData() returns. All along, i was under the impression that it's an instance of a Data struct, representing a buffer of bytes. However, it appears one can also append "()" to the returned value and it will compile, as if calling a closure with no arguments! Can't decipher what's happening.

Tried the following in XCode Playground. See output in comments:

```
let image = UIImage()
let png = UIImage.pngData(image)
print(type(of: png))   //prints --->   () -> Optional<Data>
print(type(of: png())) //prints --->   Optional<Data>
```

What is going on? Is png variable above an instance of a **closure** which takes no arguments and returns a Data optional?

FYI, Apple documentation's declaration of UIImage.pngData() is:

```
func pngData() -> Data?
```

How is it possible to use "()" on a structure instance?

Comment: You have it all wrong. You want: `let image = ... // some UIImage instance` followed by `let data = image.pngData()`. Now `data` is an instance of `Data?`.

Comment: What you observed is described here: https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/.

Comment: Or http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECsecretInstanceMethods

Comment: The directions in the comments turned out to be very useful.